# Java 8 predicate OR and removeIf strange behavior

Tags: java, lambda

Ok so have I wanted to use Predicate.or(other) instead of writing || inside a Predicate but when I am using with removeIf of ArrayList it looks like only the first check is performed here is a code example:

```
    public static void main(String... args) {
    List<String> leters = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C"));
    Predicate<String> predicate = str -> str.equals("A");
    predicate.or(str -> str.equals("B"));
    predicate.or(str -> str.equals("C"));
    leters.removeIf(predicate);
    System.out.println(leters); // Prints B,C. I was acpecting to get an empty list

    Predicate<String> predicate2 = str -> str.equals("A") || str.equals("B") || str.equals("C");
    leters = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C"));
    leters.removeIf(predicate2);
    System.out.println(leters); // Prints []
}
```

Comment: Besides the answers, here is a single line solution : `Predicate.isEqual("A").or(str->str.equals("B")).or(str->str.equals("C"));`

Answer (score 3):

`or` returns a new `Predicate` but you are ignoring the returned value:

```
Predicate<String> predicate = str -> str.equals("A");
predicate = predicate.or(str -> str.equals("B"));
predicate = predicate.or(str -> str.equals("C"));
```

Answer (score 2):

`predicate.or(str -> str.equals("B"))` doesn't mutate the original `Predicate`, it returns a new one.

You need to assign the returned `Predicate`s to the `predicate` variable:

```
Predicate<String> predicate = str -> str.equals("A");
predicate = predicate.or(str -> str.equals("B"));
predicate = predicate.or(str -> str.equals("C"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You're ignoring the result form the `or` method hence the outcome:

Instead, do:

```
 predicate = predicate.or(str -> str.equals("B"))
                      .or(str -> str.equals("C"));
```